# Want to put a variable into os.system command on Python 3, but it doesn't work

Tags: raspbian, camera

I want to use this command:

```python
thenumber=0

os.system('raspistill -o image(thenumber).jpg')
time.sleep(3)
thenumber=thenumber+1
```

I have imported the OS and Time so this script should work.

My aim is to have it so when it takes a picture, it will change the name of the file and create a new one, so we can have multiple pictures from one script.

Comment: Your question's a wee bit vague - is there an error message of some kind? What happens when you run it?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Could you please explain what the problem is (just like goobering asked)?

Answer (score 6):

Use [format strings](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#formatstrings).

```python
'raspistill -o image{0:02d}.jpg'.format(thenumber)
```

The `{0:02d}` formats the parameter to format as a 2 digit integer with leading zeros.

I also recommend using the [subprocess package](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html) instead of `os.system` it gives you more control over the how the command is run and how the out put is captured. In the simple case `os.system` can be replaced with `subprocess.call`.

```python
return_code = subprocess.call('raspistill -o image{0:02d}.jpg'.format(thenumber), shell=True)
```

Comment: For readability, I'd prefer to format the string in one line, and feed it to the function in a second, but good answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
os.system('raspistill -o image'+ thenumber +'.jpg')
```